Fixed headline change on scrolling to another section
I have been trying to achieve the same text change effect on scroll which is there on the website https://www.helmutlang.com/ I did try doing it using parallax JS and also with waypoint but I'm unable to position the fixed headline into theier each respective column. Can you please try and give me some pointers on how do i go about this. Below is my codepen
https://codepen.io/cancerian73/pen/bGypRjy
<div class="landing__container">
<div id="section1" class="section">
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 1">
    <div class="column-content">Section 1 Content</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="section2" class="section">
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 2 - Column 1">
    <div class="column-content">Column 1 Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 2 - Column 2">
    <div class="column-content">Column 2 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="section3" class="section">
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 3 - Column 1">
    <div class="column-content">Column 1 Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 3 - Column 2">
    <div class="column-content">Column 2 Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 3 - Column 3">
    <div class="column-content">Column 3 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="section4" class="section">
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 4 - Column 1">
    <div class="column-content">Column 1 Content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-column" data-headline="Welcome to Section 4 - Column 2">
    <div class="column-content">Column 2 Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
 <div class="fixed-headline-container">
<div class="fixed-headline">Welcome to Section 1</div>
 </div>

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    const fixedHeadline = document.querySelector(".fixed-headline");
    const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");

    const observerOptions = {
    root: null,
    rootMargin: "0px",
    threshold: 0.5
    };

     const observerCallback = (entries) => {
       entries.forEach((entry) => {
         if (entry.isIntersecting) {
    const headline = entry.target.querySelector(".section-column").dataset
      .headline;
    fixedHeadline.textContent = headline;
    }
     });
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);

    sections.forEach((section) => {
    observer.observe(section);
    });
    });

